# Show that graph of operator with adjoint operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $X,Y$ be inner-product spaces. Let $T\in L\left(X,Y\right)$ be a linear operator with adjoint operator $S\in L\left(Y,X\right)$ such that
$$\langle Tx,y\rangle_Y=\langle x,Sy\rangle_X\quad\forall (x,y)\in X\times Y.$$

I need to show that the graph $\mathscr{G}(T)=\{(x,Tx)\in X\times Y\;|\;x\in X\}$ is closed. Since inner-product spaces always have an extension to a normed space, there is a norm (only, I don't know if this information will be of any use here). We also know that continuous and bounded operators are the same in those "nice" linear spaces.

Now, what is left to show is that $\mathscr{G}(T)=\overline{\mathscr{G}(T)}$; i.e. all limit points in the graph of $T$ are again in the graph of $T$. Let $(x_n,Tx_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathscr{G}(T)$ which goes to the point $(x,y)$; i.e. showing that $y\in \text{Im}(T)$. In other words, we need to show that $T$ is continuous in order to conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n=T(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)=Tx$. Now, maybe we can do the following:
$$
\langle\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n,y\rangle_Y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle Tx_n,y\rangle_Y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n,Sy\rangle_X=\langle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n,Sy\rangle_X=\langle x,Sy\rangle_X=\langle Tx,y\rangle_Y=\langle T(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n),y\rangle_Y\quad\forall y\in Y.
$$
Now we have that 
$$
\langle\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n,y\rangle_Y-\langle T(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n),y\rangle_Y=\langle\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n-T(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n),y\rangle_Y=0\quad\forall y\in Y.
$$
Hence, we choose $y=\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n-T(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)$ and therefore we can conclude that, using the definition of an inner-product: $\langle x,x\rangle=0\iff x=0$, we now have $\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n=T(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)$. Q.E.D.

Is this the right way to use the adjointness of $T$ and $S$ in order to show that $(x,y)$ is an element of $T$'s graph? Thanks for the time!

Comment: As stated, it is not true. If it were true, then by taking $X=Y$, we would get  that every linear operator defined on $X$ is closed, hence by the Closed Graph Theorem, is bounded. But this is of course not true. Something is missing.

Comment: @uniquesolution This is exactly how the problem is proposed in the exercise class.

Comment: @uniquesolution What do you think of my attempt? Does that make it more clear on what I want to try to prove?

Comment: @uniquesolution No, you assume that every linear operator has an everywhere defined adjoint. That is where you slipped in the assumption of boundedness.

Comment: The paragraph about what you need to show is a bit mixed up. You don't need to show (and don't show) that $T$ is continuous. However, what you write afterwards is a correct proof of the closedness of $T$.

Comment: @MaoWao I never assumed that every linear operator has an everywhere defined adjoint. I assume that we have a **certain linear operator** which has an everywhere defined adjoint. Why would it not be valid to define the operator this way? Also, did I not prove the closedness of the graph of $T$ with this?        Btw, I now changed the formulation of the question a very little bit to accentuate that we start with an everywhere defined adjoint operator of a linear operator. P.S. I just noticed that your reply was concerning another's comment, not mine. I leave this here still, to emphasize.

Comment: @Algebear Yes, my first comment was directed at uniquesolution, who said the statement couldn't be true. You *did* show that $T$ has a closed graph. What you didn't show is that $T$ is continuous as you announced in the second paragraph (and you don't need to prove this for the original statement).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way to prove the result. Let $(x,z)\in \overline{G(T)}$ be any element then there exist a sequence $(x_n,z_n)=(x_n,Tx_n)$ in $G(T)$ such that $(x_n,Tx_n)\rightarrow (x,z)$ in $X\times Y$. Then, $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$ and $T(x_n)\rightarrow z$ in $Y$. By using the continuity of inner product we have, for any $y\in Y$,  $ \langle x,Sy\rangle=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\langle x_{n},Sy\rangle$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\langle Tx_n,y\rangle=\langle z,y\rangle$. Now, for any $y\in Y$, we have
$$\ \langle Tx, y\rangle =\langle x,Sy\rangle,\  (\text{by using the properties of adjoint operator } S )\\ =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\langle x_n,Sy\rangle, (\text{by using the observation above }) \\= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\langle Tx_n,y\rangle ,(\text{by using    properties of adjoint})\\ = \langle z,y\rangle, (\text{by using the aboveobservation above }) .$$ So, we have $\langle Tx, y\rangle = \langle z,y\rangle, \forall y\in Y.$ This implies that $z=Tx$. The, $(x,z)=(x,Tx)\in G(T)$ and since $(x,z)\in \overline{G(T)}$ is arbitrary point, we get $\overline{G(T)}\subseteq G(T).$ So we get, $G(T)=\overline{G(T)}$, i.e $G(T)$ is closed in $X\times Y.$ Hence, the operator $T: X\rightarrow Y$ is closed. In similar way one can prove the adjoint operator $S:Y\rightarrow X$ is closed operator.